# Highcharts Heatmap Set Column Width

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to change the size of a column in a heatmap. I can use the `colsize` to set the width of the border, but i'd like to change the width of the entire column. Is this possible?
Here's a JS fiddle example.

http://jsfiddle.net/8b9410om/

The `Total` column I would like to change to the same size at the border that you can see around it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `endOnTick` and `pointPlacement` properties:

```
xAxis: {
  ...,
  max: 1.25,
  endOnTick: false
},

series: [...,
  {
    colsize: 0.25,
    pointPlacement: -1.5,
    ...
  }
]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/t3r12hnk/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.heatmap.pointPlacement

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.max